# Efficiently assign a value within predefined range in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

The objective is to assign new value within certain range (b_top,b_low).

The code below able to achieve the intended objective

```
b_top=np.array([1,7])
b_low=np.array([3,9])+1
Mask=np.zeros((1,11), dtype=bool)
for x,y in zip(b_top,b_low):
    Mask[0,x:y]=True
```

However, I wonder there is single line approach, or more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn `b_top` and `b_low` into a mask using `np.cumsum` and the fact that `bool` and `int8` are the same itemsize.

```
header = np.zeros(M.shape[1], np.uint8)
header[b_top] = 1
header[b_low if b_low[-1] < header.size else b_low[:-1]] = -1
header.cumsum(out=Mask[0].view(np.int8))
```

I've implemented this function in a little utility library I made. The function is called [`haggis.math.runs2mask`](https://github.com/madphysicist/haggis/blob/8e4b84052e4406849f0e55b2db4d50e4975b779b/src/haggis/math.py#L545). You would call it as

```
from haggis.math import runs2mask

Mask[0] = runs2mask(np.stack((b_top, b_low), -1), Mask.shape[1])
```

Comment: Excellent and neat as always